# How to display Lines between Brackets in c#

Tags: c#

I want to display Lines between Brackets in C# text editor
like this image!
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ9Ok.png)

Thx

Comment: In Visual Studio? That looks like CodeRush to me, which is a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this without paying for CodeRush is to use the Indent Guides extension for Visual Studio:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30